# amending duplicated field with awk

Tags: awk, duplicates, gawk

I have a file with two tab separated columns, an ID and sequence column.

```
122_mex1 TGCAGGC
122_mex1 TGAAAAA
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGC
```

I would like to amend the end of the ID column (column 1) for each line that has a duplicate ID (column 1) -- in this toy dataset, the result would be to change the 2nd instance of 122_mex1 and 122_mex2, appending a "b" on the ID for these lines:

```
122_mex1 TGCAGGC
122_mex1b TGAAAAA
122_mex2 TGCAGTC
122_mex2b TGCAGTC
122_can4 TGCATTT
239_mex1 TGCAAAA
239_mex2 TGCAAAA
239_can4 TGCAGC
```

while all other lines without any duplicates are simply printed as is.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
LP

Comment: How many times can one id occur in the input data: (only  once or twice)  or (more often). In case an id is used a third time: should it be amended by 'bb' or by 'c'? What happens for a fourth duplicate, etc.?

Comment: there will never be a 3rd (or more) duplicate

Comment: Is the data sorted like this already or can the duplicate values in column 1 appear anywhere in the file?

Comment: the data may not be sorted-duplicate IDs may not be sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an awk script (`doubles.awk`) tested with GNU awk :

```
BEGIN { IFS = OFS = "\t" }
1   { 
      print $1 ids[ $1 ], $2
      ids[ $1 ] = "b"
    }
```

Say your input is in `doubles.csv`, run the script like this `awk -f doubles.awk doubles.csv`.

Answer (score 2):

If there are arbitrarily numerous potential duplicates, I'd go with perl:

```
perl -lane '
    if ($. > 1) {
        if ($prev ne $F[0]) {
            $ext = "";
        } else {
            $ext ||= "a";   # so we start with "b"
            ++$ext;
        }
    }
    $prev = $F[0];
    $F[0] .= $ext;
    print join(" ", @F);
' file
```

perl has a strange feature where the `++` operator can increment strings: "a" => "b", ... "z" => "aa", "aa" => "ab", etc.

This assumes your input file is sorted on ID

Comment: Nice hint about the ++ for strings, I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$1=$1(a[$1]++?"b":"")}1' file

122_mex1        TGCAGGC
122_mex1b       TGAAAAA
122_mex2        TGCAGTC
122_mex2b       TGCAGTC
122_can4        TGCATTT
239_mex1        TGCAAAA
239_mex2        TGCAAAA
239_can4        TGCAGC
```